# Elements inside scrollview shows different size for different screens. How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

im my code

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/json"
            android:onClick="album"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/json1"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="live"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

how can i set height of the imageviews independent for all size screens...

now it looks fine in mobile phones but on tabs, the imageviews insdie scrollview get stretched.

Answer (score 1):

Those are stretched because of scaleType,
Set it to centerInside and it will work fine.

Comment: i want it to have the same width as its parent linear layout.

Comment: That will create h problem as you will need to maintain aspect ratio of the image and you don't have a fixed height, centreCrop will do the same but it will zoom image to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Three XML attributes are defining how your image appears on the screen.

1. Height
2. Width
3. Scale Type

You've set the height to `140dp`, but set the width to be `fill_parent` and the scale type to `fitXY`.

Set the Image width to be `140dp` or some other predefined value based on the Image Aspect Ratio or change the scale type.

Comment: if i dont put fitxy, the images in imageview wont fit in the entire width as the parent layout.

Comment: Check your images width and height and set it in the XML. Then there is no need for scale type.

Comment: If you want the image width to fit the parent layout then you've to sacrifice the aspect ratio or you have to set different heights for different screen sizes.